# AJAX and JSON not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm just getting started with AJAX and JSON and it's been a very frustrating ride. I'm trying to implement my JSON file and check if it is a success by logging "OK" inside the function. Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  var dat;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "API.json",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("OK");
      $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        console.log("OK");
      })
    }
  })
})
```

Here is the AJAX file:

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'James',
  drink: 'Coffee'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'John',
  drink: 'Latte'
},]
```

However it never logs anything, either in the beginning of the function nor inside the each loop. Any ideas?

Comment: First obvious idea is add some error handling

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? if you expect to receive json then add `dataType: 'json',`.

Comment: No no errors. Just emptiness

Comment: Check the network tab of the console after making the request. You can check the response code of the request and also see exactly what the response text is. In your case it should be 200 and the contents of your JSON file. If it's anything else, please edit your question to include it

Comment: I would also check if `yoursite.com/API.json` is being served by going to that url in your browser

Comment: Yes in the network tab the JSON file is loaded and it has 200 status displaying an array of the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try change the format of your data in JSON file to something like and try now,

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "James",
  "drink": "Coffee"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "John",
  "drink": "Latte"
}]

$('#btn').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('path/API.json', function(data) {
       console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried that. When I click on the button it gets the file in the Network but doesn't log anything

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the file system, means your HTML file is in some folder and you tried to access it directly from their like (file:///E:/SmapleDemo/Sample.html) then it will not work.

It throws the cross-origin error.

Try to setup application with any web server like IIS and access it from there. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

While making any webservice call client has to mention the datatype and content type headers.
You Can refer below code :

```
$(function() {
    $('#btnGetData').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'URL',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(response) {
                $('#data').html(JSON.stringify(response));
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

in your code you have not mentioned datatype and content type . Try adding this and it will work. If still error exists try accessing that webservice using browser and check whether it is responding correct data.

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work even when I add those lines

Comment: can you log the error to console so that we will exact reason for it.

Comment: Here is the error: {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}